# How could i set default value for mutiple dropdown using javascript(jQuery ajax whatever)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I m working on my web tech experiment myself. i have two dropdown lists quoted in a div.

```
<div id="A">
<select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
</select>
</div>
```

And here my javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#A option:eq(1)').attr("selected", "selected");
});
```

What i expect is dropdown lists with option "2" and "7", but only got "2" but "7".oh, can i make it happen by oneline script code (instead setting two div with two tag for two dropdown) Thanks a lot for reply and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/7zBF2/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#A select').each(function () {
        $(this).find('option:eq(1)').prop("selected", "selected");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#A').find('select option:nth-child(2)').attr("selected", "selected");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
$('select').find('option:eq(1)').attr("selected", "selected");
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first seletor it's selection only first matched element.

Use [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

> Get the descendants of **each element** in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

Try

```
$('#A>select').find('option:eq(1)').attr("selected", "selected");
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshbm13/asCVU/7/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#A > select option[value=2]).eq(0).attr('selected','selected');
$('#A > select option[value=7]).eq(1).attr('selected','selected');
```

Comment: Missing  `Write less Do more`  slogan :)

Comment: he could do that even using this
<option selected="selected">2</option>
...
<option selected="selected">7</option>

No js needed (according to you less code right then ?) . what if he had to select value 5 from the first list and value 6 from the second list ?

Answer (score 0):

```
use this.

<div id="A">
<select id="s1">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
</select>
<select id="s2">
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
</select>
</div>


----------


$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#s1 option:eq(1)').attr("selected", "selected");
        $('#s2 option:eq(1)').attr("selected", "selected");
});
```